# Consulta SQL retornando dados caso o valor do where seja parcial

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Fiz uma procedure para retornar os dados da tabela *dbo.AspNetUserClaims*.
Ao executar a procedure com o token exato ela tras os dados normalmente, mas se tiver caractere no final da proc ela tamb retorna.

Exemplo:

1 Meu token é: EF99DE1F-62AB-47E1-A1DA-487DECE34D12

2 Ao rodar a proc e no inicio do token eu adicionar um x ela nao retorna dados. exec Administrativo.spValidarTokenUsuario 'xEF99DE1F-62AB-47E1-A1DA-487DECE34D12', 'meuusuario@hotmail.com'

3 Ao fazer ao contrario adicionando o caractere no final, ele esta retornando dados e o certo seria retornar dados caso o token passado seja identico o que esta cadastrado em meu claims exec Administrativo.spValidarTokenUsuario 'EF99DE1F-62AB-47E1-A1DA-487DECE34D12X', 'meuusuario@hotmail.com'

Tentei bastante coisa já, mas não consigo obter esse resultado.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Administrativo.spValidarTokenUsuario (@UsuarioToken VARCHAR(36), 
@Usuario VARCHAR(256))
AS
BEGIN
-- Declare as variáveis necessárias
DECLARE @ValidarUsuarioExistente INT;
DECLARE @RetornarUsuarioId INT;

-- Verifica se o usuário foi informado
IF (@Usuario IS NULL)
    THROW 51000, 'Por favor informar o usuário.', 1;

-- Verifica se o usuário existe
SET @ValidarUsuarioExistente = Administrativo.fnVerificarUsuarioExistente(@Usuario);
IF (@ValidarUsuarioExistente = 0)
    THROW 51000, 'Usuário inválido, tente novamente por favor!', 1;

-- Verifica se o usuário existe
SET @RetornarUsuarioId = Administrativo.fnRetornarUsuarioId(@Usuario);
IF (@RetornarUsuarioId = 0)
    THROW 51000, 'Não foi possível encontrar o usuário, tente novamente por favor!', 1;

-- Seleciona as claims do usuário
SELECT 
    claims.Id,
    claims.UserId,
    claims.ClaimType,
    claims.ClaimValue
FROM dbo.AspNetUserClaims claims
     JOIN dbo.AspNetUsers aspNetUser ON aspNetUser.Id = claims.UserId
     JOIN Administrativo.Usuarios usuarios ON usuarios.Token = @UsuarioToken
WHERE claims.ClaimValue = @UsuarioToken
    AND LEN(claims.ClaimValue) = LEN(@UsuarioToken)
      AND claims.ClaimType = 'UsuarioToken'
      AND aspNetUser.Email = @Usuario;
 END;
```

Valores dentro do claims

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual problema ? O que está gravado em claims.ClaimType ? Neste caso a busca tem de ser exata.

Comment: O problema conforme citei acima é que quando executo a procedure com o token correto e nesse token coloco ao final mais algum caractere o mesmo esta trazendo minha consulta, sendo que o que estou precisando criar seria uma consulta que retornasse caso o token passo for = ao token que esta dentro do claims

Deixei um exemplo para simpleficar, mas o problema é quando eu coloco caractere do lado direito do meu token válido. Ela esta me trazendo sendo que meu token fica diferente.

Sobre o que tem dentro dela, deixei uma imagem acima tamb.

Comment: Na hora que vc compara será algo como WHERE RTRIM(LTRIM(claims.ClaimValue)) = RTRIM(LTRIM(@UsuarioToken)), que compara a string exatamente e remove tudo a direita ou a esquerda, não resolve?

Comment: A entrada da  SP é varchar de 36 , o tamanho da string , em Oracle uma entrada maior tomaria erro , o comportamento pode estar vindo da truncagem no "x" final. O comportamento em Sql Server pode ser diferente.

Comment: @FlavioBarros Acredita que não?rs

Pelo que vi aqui isso é uma característica do SQL Server :/

Comment: @Motta então pelo que vi aqui é uma característica do SQL Server, na minha cabeça teria que ser igual a Oracle mesmo porque não faz muito sentido isso.